# C# The Wrong (maybe duplicate) Barcode Issued (with BarcodeLib Reference)

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-printing

Now, I have solved the 1st problem. Thanks to Mihai Ovidiu Drăgoi. But it's still looped.

[Newest barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDhEE.png)

Newest code:

```
        var checkbarcode = (
            from x in db.pelanggan
            where x.barcodepelanggan.Equals(textBox2.Text)
            select x).FirstOrDefault();

        int W = Convert.ToInt32(100);
        int H = Convert.ToInt32(20);
        b.Alignment = BarcodeLib.AlignmentPositions.CENTER;

        BarcodeLib.TYPE type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.UNSPECIFIED;

        type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.UPCA;

        b.RotateFlipType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;

        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = b.Encode(type, this.textBox2.Text.Trim(), this.btnwarnaBarcode.BackColor, this.btnwarnaLatar.BackColor, W, H);


        pictureBox1.Location = new Point((this.pictureBox1.Location.X + this.pictureBox1.Width / 2) - pictureBox1.Width / 2, (this.pictureBox1.Location.Y + this.pictureBox1.Height / 2) - pictureBox1.Height / 2);
```

I'm trying to issue my the barcode, and success, but after i scan using the barcode scanner, this barcode is undetected. After i search the problem in the google, the problem is maybe because it looped. I have the comparison of the barcode (which is from different program, here the comparison.

Here is the picture that maybe help you to see the comparison:

[image: The True one] (1)- [image: My issued Barcode (The Wrong one)] (2)

But after i see the code and compare them, there's not have any different that may causing trouble in my barcode issuing. I use the same barcode type which is, UPC-A.

Here my code:

```
            var checkbarcode = (
            from x in db.pelanggan
            where x.barcodepelanggan.Equals(textBox2.Text)
            select x).FirstOrDefault();

        int W = Convert.ToInt32(100);
        int H = Convert.ToInt32(20);
        b.Alignment = BarcodeLib.AlignmentPositions.CENTER;

        BarcodeLib.TYPE type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.UNSPECIFIED;

        type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.UPCA;

        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = b.Encode(type, this.textBox2.Text.Trim(), this.btnwarnaLatar.BackColor, this.btnwarnaBarcode.BackColor, W, H);

        pictureBox1.Location = new Point((this.pictureBox1.Location.X + this.pictureBox1.Width / 2) - pictureBox1.Width / 2, (this.pictureBox1.Location.Y + this.pictureBox1.Height / 2) - pictureBox1.Height / 2);
```

The idea is, when the txtbarcode changed, the barcode is printed on the picture box at the right side or user's card group box.

Any help from you may help me to scan the barcode without it being looped. Thanks in advance :D

The true code as the reference: www.codeproject.com/Articles/20823/Barcode-Image-Generation-Library

Comment: "But after i see the code and compare them, there's not have any different" - Well to *my* eyes, the barcodes shown are **very** different ...

Comment: @Fildor hmm i just copy paste the codes (not all LOC) from the right program. Because of that, i say the code is not different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, found it - the colors are inverted. If you download the second image and invert colors, any scanner will read the correct value. Check your code and make sure you aren't inverting colors anywhere.

Or, maybe it's easier - simply invert them again before displaying them.

PS - you probably just need to switch `this.btnwarnaLatar.BackColor` and  `this.btnwarnaBarcode.BackColor` in your `b.Encode()`

Comment: hmm? how this can be done? i just follow the rules on the color.

Comment: try the PS part of my answer.

Comment: hmm i see.. It goes true. But the barcode is too many

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywwXmd4D1rDQ2lmaWtoYmd3cW8

Comment: hmm.. i mean if you see the barcode it's like this
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywwXmd4D1rDVGhvVTdvYUxRQUk

Comment: The barcode generator tool has an option where you selected "RotateNoneFlipNone". Your code needs to do the same.

Comment: ah i see.. i'll back soon after revise it

Comment: b.RotateFlipType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;

This is the code? if yes, i've already been put it over there but nothing change

Comment: Please update your post with the new code - it probably has to be before the b.Encode()

Comment: As I was saying - the b.RotateFlipType probably needs to be BEFORE the b.Encode(). Please try that.

Comment: hmm it's still can't :') i've update it on my answer. see it

Comment: do you get the exact same image even after you moved the b.RotateFlipType before the b.Encode()?

Comment: Can you try changing W and H to 300 and 150 (as they are in the demo app)? maybe the library has some internal processing that causes that looping.

Comment: hmm after i try your advice, yes it can't loop. But the new problem is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywwXmd4D1rDYm16bjU0MlVESTA

Comment: pictureBox1 is now too small to display all of the barcode. You need to resize it first. As a test, simply make the pictureBox larger, check that the barcode is readable, and then resize it in code.

Comment: To make clear: as a final solution, you need to resize the image of the barcode, not the pictureBox. However, as a test, you can resize (enlarge) the pictureBox first to make sure everything is alright.